# Error X in code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem in my code (`if(x.selected)`).

Error is that *the name x does not exist in the current context*.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int sum = 0;


        foreach (ListItem x in CheckBoxList1.Items) ;
        if (x.Selected)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(x.Value);

        }
        Label1.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `;` at the end of your `foreach()` statement, terminating the statement right there. The code following it, therefore, cannot see or access `x` since it's already out of scope.

Comment: thanx for the help